# How to handle promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise

I am having an issue with Promises, I have writted a function which tries to get data from Shared preferences and once I receive it, I return a `Promise`.
   In the function I am using it returns `Unhandled promise rejection cannot read the property then of undefined`

Here is my function which gets the data from shared preferences and returns a promise

```
  export function isMock(){
    const returned = getSharedPreferenceValue( Globals.SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY_IS_TEST_USER).then ((isTestUser) => {  
        consoleLog('isMock - ' + isTestUser);//THIS LINE WORKS 
        return Promise.resolve(isTestUser === 'true' ? true : false);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        consoleLog('error -' + err);
        return {error:err, response: null};
      });
}
```

Here is the function where I am trying to use the above function.

```
export function login ( abcd, xyz ){

    const returned = isMock().then((isMock) => {
        //Do some based on isMock.
        console.log(`Login isMock - ` + isMock); //DOES NOT PRINT
    })
    .catch(error => {
          console.log('Login isMock - error - ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      });
}
```

Here is the error message

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Could you please suggest where I am going wrong.

Update

After following the answer creating New promise resolved the issue in that function but the error was coming from another one.

function inMock which is now fixed

```
export function isMock(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getSharedPreferenceValue(Globals.SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY_IS_TEST_USER).then(isTestUser => {
          consoleLog('isMock - ' + isTestUser);
          resolve(isTestUser === 'true' ? true : false);
        }).catch(err => {
          consoleLog('error -' + err);
          reject(err)
        });
      });
}
```

isMock is called here and issue is in else statement which returns a promise

```
export function login ( ABCD, XYZ ){
    const returned = isMock().then((isMock) => {
        consoleLog('login Legacy API - isMock() - ' + isMock);//THIS WORKS
        if(!isMock){
            console.log('isMock is false');
        }else{

            consoleLog('mock data - ../mockData/login.json');
            var user = require('../mockData/login.json');//WORKS

            return Promise.resolve(user);//PROBLEM MIGHT BE HERE
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
          console.log('Login isMock - error - ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      });
}
```

Main calling function of Login is here which gives me the error

```
loginUser_legacy = async (ABCD, XYZ) => {  
    const returned = await login(cardDigits, nationalIdNumber).then((res) => {
      consoleLog('res - ' + res);//DOES NOT WORK
    });

  }
```

Thanks
R

Comment: Your `login` function has the same problem that your `isMock` function had. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: does this line `return Promise.resolve(user);` in Login does not return it?

Comment: No, that line is inside an inner function that won't even execute until long after the login function is already done.. The `login` function itself has no `return` statement.

Answer (score 2):

I think, are you not returning `returned` in `isMock()` ?

So although in the `catch` you return `{error:err, response: null}`, you never actually get an error as you are `return Promise.resolve(isTestUser === 'true' ? true : false);` which always returns a `resolved` (albeit resolved with a `true` or `false`) and thus never goes into the catch (which is also async so isn't aaccctually returned)

edit, possible what to do:

```
export function isMock(){
  return new Promise((res,rej)=> {
   getSharedPreferenceValue(Globals.SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY_IS_TEST_USER).then ((isTestUser) => {  
    res(isTestUser === 'true')
  }).catch(rej)
 }
```

}

A new promise is returned; this will `getSharedPreferenceValue`, if this succeeds then resolve the new promise with your answer.  If this fails, pass the error into the reject function which will also pass back to the `isMock()` caller which will catch it.

Comment: so what are recommending to do?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the function should be getSharedPreferences() not getSharedPreferencesValue()

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use Promise.resolve since getSharedPreferenceValue itself is a promise... you could try to return just the values....

also you should not resolve a promise inside a thenable function as per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

you could try this way or you could simply use async/await

```
export function isMock(){
const returned = getSharedPreferenceValue( Globals.SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY_IS_TEST_USER).then ((isTestUser) => {  
    consoleLog('isMock - ' + isTestUser);//THIS LINE WORKS 
    return isTestUser === 'true' ? true : false;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    consoleLog('error -' + err);
    return {error:err, response: null};
  });
```

}

Comment: I did try this too but that did not work either but will give another try

Comment: Tried that again which did not work. @Varun The Falcon

Comment: okay, what is the nature of this fn getSharedPreferenceValue... is it a promise? or does it take call backs?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a new Promise.

```js
export function isMock() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getSharedPreferenceValue(Globals.SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY_IS_TEST_USER).then(isTestUser => {
      consoleLog('isMock - ' + isTestUser);
      resolve(isTestUser === 'true' ? true : false)
    }).catch(err => {
      consoleLog('error -' + err);
      reject(err)
    })
  })
}
```

**-- Update --**

Promise.resolve(user) will return promise for this scope only which is isMock().

```js
export function login ( ABCD, XYZ ){
  const returned = isMock().then((isMock) => {
      consoleLog('login Legacy API - isMock() - ' + isMock);
      if(!isMock){
          console.log('isMock is false');
      }else{

          consoleLog('mock data - ../mockData/login.json');
          var user = require('../mockData/login.json');

          return Promise.resolve(user); // This line will return Promise for this scope only (isMock function)
      }
  })
  .catch(error => {
        console.log('Login isMock - error - ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

So to fix this, return a new Promise.

```js
export function login(ABCD, XYZ) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    isMock()
      .then((isMock) => {
        consoleLog(`login Legacy API - isMock() - ${isMock}`);
        if (!isMock) {
          consoleLog('isMock is false');
        } else {
          consoleLog('mock data - ../mockData/login.json');
          const user = require('../mockData/login.json');
          resolve(user);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        consoleLog(`Login isMock - error - ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello @Sanyam that did fix in that part of the function but error was coming from another function. These promises are confusing me more now.
I have updated my questions a little bit can you have a look please.

Comment: Hello @Sanyam Jain I have updated my question a bit more.
your solution solved part of the problem but the error was coming from Login function